# Python program is not returning the destination_index?

Tags: python-3.x

I want the program to return destination_index but it is not returning it. It shows nothing on the console.

```
destinations = ['Paris, France','Shanghai, China','Los Angeles, USA','São Paulo, Brazil','Cairo, Egypt']

test_traveler = ['Erin Wilkes', 'Shanghai, China', ['historical site', 'art']]
def get_destination_index(destination):
  for destination_index in range(len(destinations)):

    if destination == destinations[destination_index]:
      return destination_index

get_destination_index('Cairo, Egypt')
```

Comment: you have to print it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to add a print statement

```
destinations = ['Paris, France','Shanghai, China','Los Angeles, USA','São Paulo, Brazil','Cairo, Egypt']

test_traveler = ['Erin Wilkes', 'Shanghai, China', ['historical site', 'art']]

def get_destination_index(destination):
  for destination_index in range(len(destinations)):
    if destination == destinations[destination_index]:
      return destination_index

print(get_destination_index('Cairo, Egypt'))
```

And the output will be

```
4
```